# How to improve macro photo sharpness?

Tags: macro, depth-of-field, sharpness

I was playing with an old point and shoot camera and I made this close-up photo of a pepper:

[image]

I took many photos and it seems I can’t get a sharp image across the whole object. Can I make this better with settings? Is 8 megapixels not enough?

Or is my point-and-shoot camera really that bad that the only chance of improving this image is with a new camera body and a better lens (macro lens)? If so, what cheaper options do I have (beginner lens + extension tube)?

My settings:
f7.1 
1/4 sec 
ISO-80 
Camera model: Canon PowerShot S5 IS
Focal length: 6mm

I took another photo: 
[image]
The front side seems sharp enough but how can I make the left side that is further away from the camera just as sharp?
f/8
1/5 sec
ISO-80

Comment: Is that a hand held shot?

Comment: It was placed on a desk and I used a timer to take the photo with a short delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the *Depth of Focus* by closing the aperture (like f/22, or even f/45).

That has other side effects, though - you get less light, potentially higher ISO and more noise, diffraction, etc.; but you could just add more light or take longer shutter times (peppers don't move around, fortunately).

Professionals typically do *Focus-Stacking*; that means you take multiple shots (with a tripod), with slightly changing focus planes, and then combine them together in processing software. For example, Adobe PhotoShop does that nearly automatically.

Comment: (Many point-and-shoots don't stop down beyond f/8, though, since diffraction limiting can occur beyond that with tiny sensors.)